# How to decode a url encoding string on Windows Mobile?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, urlencode

I have received an url encoding string from the server, e.g **http%3a%2f%2fstatic.csbew.com%2f%2fcreative%2fpd_test_pptv%2f320x60.png**

I want to decode it to normal url string. I find this method, but this doesn't work on compact framework.

```
string url = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(strURL, Encoding.GetEncoding("GB2312"));
```

Any idea about how to decode the string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// UrlDecodes a string without requiring System.Web
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">String to decode.</param>
    /// <returns>decoded string</returns>
    public static string UrlDecode(string text)
    {
        // pre-process for + sign space formatting since System.Uri doesn't handle it
        // plus literals are encoded as %2b normally so this should be safe
        text = text.Replace("+", " ");
        return System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(text);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UrlEncodes a string without the requirement for System.Web
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="String"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string UrlEncode(string text)
    {
        // Sytem.Uri provides reliable parsing
        return System.Uri.EscapeDataString(text);
    }
```

Originally found here: [geekstoolbox](http://forums.geekstoolbox.com/showthread.php?25871-C-.NET-CF-UrlEncode-and-Decode&p=31643)